# rewrite URL in htaccess and remove everything but parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Is it possible to turn this URL:

```
example.com/send.php?url=google.com&name=&submit=submit
```

Into this URL:

```
example.com/google.com
```

When I try I just keep getting 404 or 500 errors and it's frustrating.

Here's a few thing's I've tried.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([-\w\.]*)$ /send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]
```

If it's not possible then please could you tell me why it's not. I'm rather new to mod_rewrite and want to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !send.php
RewriteRule ^([-\w\.])$ /send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But with a different pattern `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]`  The only problem now is I can't get to the homepage. When I type `example.com` it doesn't go to the homepage. It stays on `send.php` and the `REQUEST_URI` is '/'. So mod rewrite just considers `url=` to be an empty string.

Comment: You don't need to escape the dot to match a literal dot in a character class, and you don't need the `NC` flag here, since `\w` already includes upper and lowercase letters. You would also need to extend the _pattern_ to include more characters, currently it's only matching 1 character. ie. `^([-\w.]+)$`

Comment: @penfold_32 Your homepage is rewritten because the pattern `^([^/]*)$` matches 0 characters (ie. the homepage, `/`). Change it to include 1 or more. eg. `^([^/]+)$`. However, that pattern looks too generic, based on the example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1/? [L,R=301]
```

I'm no redirect expert, but I think the question mark at the end cuts off all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not rewriting anything else just use:

```
FallBackResource /send.php
```

and parse the PATHINFO

Comment: You would need to parse the REQUEST_URI, not the PATH_INFO. (There is no additional path information on this request.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse out the parameter to use it as file/directory you should try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/send\.php\?url=([-\w\.])\&.*$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You can't match the query string with the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. But it would seem the OP is wanting to "go the other way"?

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I forgot about this. I'm more familiar with nginx where its possible.